# Tabbed content with all source in a single file

Tags: html, css

Currently, I am using something like

```
<li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="b.html">A</a></li>
<li><a href="c.html">B</a></li>
<li><a href="d.html">C</a></li>
```

where I have four html files index.html, a.html, b.html and c.html, which are selected based on the links clicked.

Instead, I want to have the content all in the same HTML file with common headers and footers and just selectively display content depending on which button was clicked.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

put content of each page in div has unique id and display all none and each a in li have id of div

**html**

```
<li><a class="div1" href="#1">A</a></li>
<li><a class="div2" href="#2">B</a></li>
<li><a class="div3" href="#3">C</a></li>
<div id="1" class="hide" style=" width:100%; height: 100px;  background-color:red; "></div>
<div id="2" class="hide" style=" width:100%; height: 100px;  background-color:gold; "></div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .hide
    {
        display:none;
    }
```

**JS**

```
   <script>
    $(function () {
        $('li').on('click', function (e) {
            var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
            window.location.hash = href;
        });
        $('.div1').on('click', function (e) {

            $("#1").removeClass("hide");
            $("#2").addClass("hide");
            $("#3").addClass("hide");
        });
        $('.div2').on('click', function (e) {


            $("#2").removeClass("hide");
            $("#1").addClass("hide");
            $("#3").addClass("hide");
        });
        $('.div3').on('click', function (e) {

            $("#3").removeClass("hide");
            $("#1").addClass("hide");
            $("#2").addClass("hide");
        });

        if (window.location.hash == "#1") {
            $("#1").removeClass("hide");
            $("#3").addClass("hide");
            $("#2").addClass("hide");
        }

        if (window.location.hash == "#2") {
            $("#2").removeClass("hide");
            $("#3").addClass("hide");
            $("#1").addClass("hide");
        }
        if (window.location.hash == "#3") {
            $("#3").removeClass("hide");
            $("#1").addClass("hide");
            $("#2").addClass("hide");
        }
    });
  </script>
```